# Displaying content of a txt file in datagrid

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, notepad

I am completely new in vb and having a trouble displaying the content of a .txt file in datagrid.

So far i can already create a .txt file (if not exists) and save the values of textbox1 to the new line in the said .txt file

Using `Dim appendText As String = "Today is: " + DateTime.Now + " | " + TextBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine`, the output (in the txt file) looks like:

> Today is: 9/25/2015 9:28:35 AM | first message
>   Today is: 9/25/2015 9:28:41 AM | second message

and so on...

The output when i clicked the btnView (displaying of content of the file in the datagrid) is

> column1 header:  Column1
>   column2 header:  Column2
>   row1 of column1: Today is: 9/25/2015 9:28:35 AM
>   row1 of column2: first message
>   row2 of column2: Today is: 9/25/2015 9:28:41 AM
>   row2 of column2: second message

using the code:

```
 Dim TextFieldParser1 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("survey.txt")
        TextFieldParser1.Delimiters = New String() {"|"}
        While Not TextFieldParser1.EndOfData

            Dim Row1 As String() = TextFieldParser1.ReadFields()
            If DataGridView1.Columns.Count = 0 AndAlso Row1.Count > 0 Then
                Dim i As Integer
                For i = 0 To Row1.Count - 1
                    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column" & i + 1, "Column" & i + 1)
                Next
            End If
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Row1)
        End While
```

**BUT** i want to display the content in the datagrid view in this format:

> column1 header:   Date and Time
>   column2 header: Message
>   row1 of column1: Today is: 9/25/2015 9:28:35 AM
>   row1 of column2: first message
>   row2 of column2: Today is: 9/25/2015 9:28:41 AM
>   row2 of column2: second message

I'm experiencing a trouble in changing the header. If anyone can help me with this i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Why would you tell `String.Split` to split on `Tab` characters when that's not what you're using to delimit the data?

Comment: @jmcilhinney i already edited the code in my question. Can you tell me what i've done wrong? i'm only having a trouble editing/changing the header

Comment: Look at where you're adding the columns.  It is displaying exactly what you're telling it to display.  If you want it to display something else then tell it to display something else.

Comment: Also, you tell your `TextFieldParser` that your delimiter is "|".  Is that actually what you're putting between the field values?  I think not.

Comment: @jmcilhinney oh. sorry i'm just new in vb and i'm still researching. okay then. `DateTime.Now + " | " + TextBox1.Text`

Comment: Think! `DateTime.Now` is one field and `TextBox1.Text` is the other.  The bit you put between them is the delimiter.  Whatever delimiter you put in the data is what you should specify as the delimiter when you want to strip out the delimiters and get the original field values back again.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I can already split the messages using | as the delimiter. :)

Comment: Yes, you can split it, but you are not splitting it properly.  I can get through a doorway with an axe too.  Open your eyes.  In what universe is " | " the same thing as "|"?  If you split on the pipe alone then you're leaving behind those spaces that you deliberately added.

Comment: @jmcilhinney okay. changed it to what you've said. but still, that is not my problem... :(

Comment: So why not actually read the comment that I left that does address your problem then?

Answer (score 0):

what jmcilhinney says is right. In your code, when you add the column, you pass two arguments: columnName and headerText. The text you use as headerText is the text you'll see in the column's header:

```
DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column" & i + 1, "Column" & i + 1)
```

So, the headerText is "Column1" or "Column2". That's the value you pass and what you are getting now.

What I'd do:

I'd add the columns out of the block "while..end while", and later, I'd fill the grid:

```
DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column1", "Date and Time")
DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column2", "Message")

While Not textFieldParser1.EndOfData
    Dim content As String() = textFieldParser1.ReadFields
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(content)
End While
```

Hope this can help you